# STL <list> Search List to Find an item property

Tags: c++, list, stl

I don't really have a very good understanding to how STL  works.

I was able to create a list and add items to it.

But now I can't seem to search through the list to find an element with a desired property.

Forgive my ignorance on this. I am very new to STL and I still struggle with some elements of C++.

Here is the code. I know it produces errors , but I would like something like this.

Thanks in advance.

```
extern list<MonsterClass> Monsters;

MonsterClass FindMonster(int x)
{
     MonsterClass Monster;
     list<MonsterClass>::iterator ListItem;

      for(ListItem = Monsters.begin(); ListItem != Monsters.end(); ++ListItem) 
      {
      if (ListItem.X == x)
         {
           Monster = ListItem;
           return Monster;
         }
      }

   return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing elements and iterators. Iterators are *placeholders* for positions in the list, they are not the elements themselves. To get to the element, you need to dereference an iterator:

```
if ((*ListItem).X == x) // or, easier: if(ListItem->X == x)
   {
     Monster = *ListItem;
     return Monster;
   }
}
```

Furthermore, you cannot return `NULL` since your `Monster` class cannot take the value `NULL` (which is a pointer). What you *can* do is return an iterator instead of the item itself. Then your function does almost exactly the same as the [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) function from the `<algorithm>` standard header.

Answer (score 3):

```
// C++03
struct by_X {
   by_X( int x ) : x(x) {}
   bool operator()( Monster const & m ) const {
      return x == m.X;
   }
   const int x;
};
std::find_if( Monsters.begin(), Monsters.end(), by_X( 5 ) );
```

If your compiler has lambda (c++0x) support:

```
std::find_if( Monsters.begin(), Monsters.end(), [=x]( Monster const & m ) { return m.X == x; } );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this very often (like, unless it's just for debugging or something like that), a list probably isn't the best choice for the job. Just for one obvious alternative, a `std::set` directly supports searching like this. In a set the search will normally be quite a bit faster as well (logarithmic instead of linear complexity).

Comment: I will try the set idea. Thanks :)